# Scala Word count jar is not running in spark

Tags: eclipse, scala, maven, hadoop, apache-spark

I'm very new to both Scala and Spark. I added the Scala IDE to Eclipse Luna. I created a maven project in the eclipse. I was to run the program within the eclipse with run as configuration option and able to get the output successfully. But when i create the jar for the following program and tried to run the spark shell am getting the following error.

> **error: ';' expected but 'class' found.**

Command use to run the jar

`spark-submit --class com.kirthi.spark.proj.sparkexamples.WordsCount --master local /home/cloudera/workspace/sparkwc1.jar hdfs://localhost:8020/kirthi3/dataset.txt hdfs://localhost:8020/kirthi3/sparkwco`

The word count program which i tried

```
package com.kirthi.spark.proj.sparkexamples
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._

object WordsCount {
 def main(args: Array[String]){

   val conf = new SparkConf()
   .setAppName("Word Count")
   .setMaster("local")

   val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

   val textFile = sc.textFile(args(0))

   val words = textFile.flatMap(line => line.split(","))

   val counts = words.map(word => (word,1))

   val wordcount = counts.reduceByKey(_+_)

   val wordcount_sorted = wordcount.sortByKey()

   wordcount_sorted.foreach(println)

   wordcount_sorted.saveAsTextFile(args(1)) 
  }

}
```

Kindly help me out in this as I am struck with initial program for spark.

I am using cloudera quickstart CDH 5.5

Comment: I am using Cloudera CDH 5.5

Comment: When running this command in your machine's shell, what is the exact output you get?

Comment: This was the error i got when ran the command to execute the jar file

<console>:1: error: ';' expected but 'class' found.

Comment: Are you trying to run the command in the Scala REPL? You need to execute it on a regular shell

Comment: yep, I ran in scala repl. Since I thought I should run this in spark shell. Now i ran it regular shell. I worked fine. Thanks Avihoo :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As shown in the comments, you ran the above command in the Scala REPL, and which you should run it from a regular linux shell.